# Does anyone know why my hard disk heads seem to be stuck on the platters?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

Does anybody know what's wrong with my old hard drives heads mechanism? At startup they go back and forth a few times, attempting to get on the platters, then the disk gives up spinning.

Any help in recovering the data left on the disk would be very appreciated.

Here is [some video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ona1CcYytzfQmrfApVoUycYEH6476R7Z/view?usp=sharing) of the drive itself. And here is a pic of the drive for reference.

[image]

Comment: By opening up the drive the way you did, you have nuked any realistic option of recovering data from that drive. You have exposed it to dust and particles that have effectively destroyed your data. The only chance you might have had to recover data was honestly to not open the drive physically like that and perhaps post here about it. But the drive would have been still dead; only clean room disassembly data recovery might have worked to restore data. At this point? The drive is 100% dead; at best a paperweight.

Answer (score 6):

You have (according to the video) a physically disassembled the drive.

I truly doubt you did this in a clean room.

So:

1. In all likelihood the drive is just dead. Dust (impossible to avoid in this situation) will damage the platters.
2. You might try a local recovery agency, but I think (because you took the drive apart) that will be very expensive. Also, since you opened it, they might refuse it. You would need to inquire.

Comment: True, but I needed a quick and cheap procedure. Dust can be a problem, I agree, but it's the mechanical issue my main concern at the moment

Comment: I do not think you can do anything with this disk now. Any dust will cause damage (even it you cannot see it)

Comment: @GioP - If there is even particle of dust on any of the platters then your data is gone. What could have done is now impossible

Comment: There appears to be a problem with the heads. There is no quick and easy solution for this. There is nothing in a hard drive that is user serviceable. You have been given a valuable lesson. Make backups before problems develop as after is often too late.

Comment: The "quick & cheap procedure" would have been to take it to a data recovery company before you opened it… or even quicker & cheaper, always have a backup. You now have a slow & expensive procedure.

Answer (score 3):

The cheap, quick and easy data recovery method is to restore from backups. Not having those is unfortunately the smaller of your mistakes.

The fact that you've disassembled the drive is what rules out the not-so-expensive solutions.

- HDDs are sensitive even to tension of the case screws. The fact that it's disassembled alone can be the reason why the heads don't work correctly.
- Heads are scratching side edge of platters, so they may be damaged. If that's the case, a head transplant will be necessary.
- The platters are now dirty because you've opened the drive outside of a clean room. Just to give you an idea: keeping the platters clean is so important that the standard 99,9% pure isopropyl alcohol is not good enough for wiping the platters.

At this point you have to find a good data recovery company and pay *a lot* to get *some* of your data.

Then it would be wise to plan your backup strategy.